# Adjusting setting from consumer's location - Collecting data to make inferences using location. (Cadio, Inc.) - Patent Application - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, mobile, us20120330722

**AN OVERBROAD PATENT ON managing information associated with a data set based on location of the consumer.** - This application from [Cadio, Inc.](http://www.locately.com/) seeks to patent the idea of...Receiving an input from a consumer, obtaining location of the consumer, identifying a setting visited by the consumer based on the obtained location, and adjusting the information associated with the identified setting based on the obtained location and input from the consumer.! 10 minutes of your time can help narrow US patent applications before they become patents.  [Follow @askpatents](https://twitter.com/AskPatents) on twitter to help.

**QUESTION** - Have you seen anything that was **published before 6/27/2011** that discusses:

> - Managing information in a data set for identifying settings visited by a consumer based on consumer's location.

If so, please submit evidence of prior art as an answer to this question. We welcome multiple answers from the same individual.

**EXTRA CREDIT** - A setting refers to a place corresponding to the consumer's location, such as a **commercial place** or a **non-commercial place** (e.g., business or park).

**TITLE: Adjusting a process for identifying a setting visited by a consumer based on the consumer's location and input received from the consumer.**

**Summary**:  [Translated from Legalese into English] Receiving location of a consumer, identifying a setting (such as **a commercial place** or **a non-commercial place** (e.g., business or park)) from a **data set** corresponding to the received location, and changing the information associated with the identified setting in the from a **data set** based on the identification process.

- **Publication Number**: [US20120330722 A1](http://www.google.com/patents/US20120330722)
- **Application Number**: US 13/535,150
- **Assignee**: Cadio, Inc.
- **Prior Art Date**: Seeking prior Art **predating** 6/27/2011
- **Open for Challenge at USPTO:** Open through 6/25/2013
- **Link to Google Prior Art Search** - ["Find Prior Art"](https://www.google.com/patents/related/US20120330722#c=0&d1&d2=06%2F27%2F2012)

**Claim 1** requires each and every step below:

> A method of operating a consumer analytics system in which information about consumers is generated at least in part based on applying a visit detection process to location data relating to one or more consumers, to identified settings visited by the one or more consumers, the method comprising:
>
> 1. Receiving input provided by a consumer identifying a setting visited by the consumer at a time;
> 2. Obtaining information identifying a physical location of the consumer at the time; and
> 3. Adjusting, using at least one processor and based at least in part on the input provided by the consumer and the physical location of the consumer, the visit detection process for identifying settings visited by the plurality of consumers.

In English this means:

> A system for:
>
> 1. Receiving input from a consumer to identify a setting visited by the consumer;
> 2. Obtaining location of the consumer;
> 3. Identifying a setting corresponding to the location of the consumer; and
> 4. Adjusting information stored in a data set used for identifying whether the consumer has visited the setting.

Good prior art would be evidence of a system that did each and every one of these steps prior to 6/27/2011

You're probably aware of ten pieces of art that meet this criteria already... separately, the applicant is claiming Comparing location of the consumer with location boundaries of one or more settings to identify a setting corresponding to the location of the consumer.

---

**"Identifying a place visited by a consumer" from the Applicant**

[image]

---

*What is good prior art? Please see our [FAQ](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#prior-art).*

*Want to help? Please vote or comment on submissions below. We welcome you to [post your own request for prior art](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prior-art-request+pre-grant) on other questionable US Patent Applications.*

---

Answer (score 2):

I have used an Android application created specifically for that purpose since before the given date.
http://web.archive.org/web/20100110203540/http://www.twofortyfouram.com/?
The web archive presents the situation and the solution prior to the patent application date.

Comment: If you look at claims or even the abstract you will see that this is about a business building up data about who visits it and specially about automatically adjusting its method of deciding if someone is at the location each time it determines someone is or isn't at the location. From my reading of it, the site you reference does something completely different.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents. FYI - the style at Ask Patents and all Stack Exchange sites is to *not* use signatures or other sayings at the end of posts.